# Tenacity/Retry in Jupyter

Tags: python, databricks, python-tenacity

I am having trouble getting tenacity / retry to work with a jupyter-like notebook in Databricks. How can I get it to re-run when an exception is met? The default use of retry is supposed to continue indefinitely.

```
from tenacity import retry
@retry
def retry_worker():
    # do stuff
```

```
try:
    retry_worker()
except Exception as e:
    raise e
```

When I am met with an exception, my cell stops totally